# How to type less/greater than (<, >) characters in US keyboard with non-US layout in settings

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I'm using a Keychron K2 with a physical US layout that I set as Italian in my settings. This means I'm missing a few keys that exists only in the physical Italian layout keyboards. Specifically the keys highlighted in yellow are missing:
[image]

My question is: how do I type the "<" and ">" characters if the key is missing?

I've dealt with this problem in the past and by pressing the right <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> I was able to type the "less than" character. This solution is not working anymore, as with that combo of keys I get this ‹ character. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For now I can only think of using Ctrl+Shift+u, an underlined u appears, and then you type the unicode character, [here's a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters), for example: `Ctrl+Shift+u` then `003c` will give you the `<` character. Give it a try.

Comment: If the keys are missing in the physical keyboard, what about in a screen keyboard. I often use `onboard` and maybe you will find the missing keys there.

Comment: Only one of the two keys is missing. The other one is above the Return key. Which Italian layout variant is this? It's packed full of AltGr combinations, but some are redundant. The AltGr+{Z,X} characters aren't intended to be the less/greater than signs `<` and `>`, they're intended to be the single-chevron quotes (used in some Central European countries).

Comment: I am able to type the >, < characters as I am using an external keyboard connected to my laptop (which has an Italian physical layout). What I'd like to understand is why the <kbd>Alt<kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> combo is not working anymore and how to remap the "less than" character to that shortcut. Thank you for your suggestion @schrodigerscatcuriosity , it works but it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find out why the shortcuts stopped working in the first place, but I managed to remap the <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>X</kbd> keys editing the keyboard layouts configuration files following [this guide](http://karols.github.io/blog/2013/11/18/creating-custom-keyboard-layouts-for-linux/).

What I did was create a custom variant of the Italian layout then overwrite the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> behaviours:

```
key <AB01>  { [         z,          Z,          less, less ] };
key <AB02>  { [         x,          X,          greater, greater ] };
```

Comment: +1+1 and thanks for sharing your solution :-)